# mysql doesn't running on xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

The image below illustrates the error that I get on **xampp**; it shows when I am about to start the MySQL: it does starts and stops immediately.

image here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCaGk.png)

What is causing the error and how can I possibly resolve it?

Comment: It is better to give the error as text rather than as an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have SQL running on port 3306 from another program.

You can change the port in the config.

Or you can shutdown the current SQL process that is running.